# VBA Code to find the row number of a date in data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA Find function to find a date from a column and then return the row number of the date.

This works:

```
Cells.Find(What:="1 Jul 13", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

But, this doesn't work:

```
Cells.Find(What:=Range("E2"), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Any idea? I want the user to input a date to "E2" and then run my code, so I would prefer to use the second way if possible.

Many thanks for your help.

Ben

Comment: What number format is E2? What error are you getting? Can you try `Sheets("sheet name").Range("E2")`?

Comment: The number format in E2 is 1Jul 13. It works for the method kindly provided by Gary's Student below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **1 Jul 13** actually appears in the cell, then use;

```
What:=Range("E2").Text
```

Comment: This should work. The function is looking for "41456" when it tries to find Range("E2") if E2 contains 1 Jul 2013 and Excel has interpreted that as a date. It doesn't find it because it searches the text in the cells it looks at - not the underlying value.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks for that. Thanks for your further explanation, John.